# What crew do I need to complete the SemiConductors R&D project in Project Space Station?

Tags: project-space-station

So I'm playing [Project Space Station](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Space_Station) in DOSBox. I'm doing the "Semi-Conductors" R&D project.

So far I've made a few breakthroughs and my current revenue is 250, but I can't seem to get past this:

The game keeps saying:

> A key scientist is needed for our research to continue. Check project description for who is needed.

My crew lineup for the project is (in order, but i'm not sure if order is important):

- Finworth (Chm)
- Rivera (Mat)
- McFarlan (Mat)
- Whiting (Cmp)

How can I complete this?

Comment: It says right there "check project description for who is needed". So what does the project description say?

Comment: I actually attempted to answer this question by actually playing the game, but it is just too annoying to try and get to this point.  I did some research, and found [an article](http://www.filfre.net/tag/project-space-station/) that says you need to just keep bringing people of different skill sets to the station in and hope it works.  I believe that you could be missing the Mat Res Pac equipment for the mission, which is needed as stated in the description for it.  You did not mention if you had it or not in your question.

Comment: I'm assuming I did have it - usually when you are missing some _equipment_ then you get told directly that you are.

Comment: I feel like there needs to be a wiki on this, somewhere :) the excel grid that lists all missions + milestones + scientists required for that milestone.

Comment: @TimmyJim, missing equipment has its own message.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this helps but on every mission that you do there is a project description option that suggests what kind of staff you need on each mission. like the picture below. So pick accordingly.
[Found insight on this site hopefully, this helps!](http://www.myabandonware.com/game/project-space-station-cc)

[image]

Comment: ur ... i'm not sure i've seen that? is this specific to an OS port?

Comment: This is specific to the apple II system game And DOS Box

Comment: The thing is though, the OP stated in their question that they had the 3 type of people already for the Semiconductors project (Mat, Cmp, Chm).  I think the game adds in another person that is needed on some projects.  If you look at my comment on the question above, you'll see that from what I've been able to find, you just need to keep bringing different people with different skill sets to the station until one works.  I can confirm though that in DOS Box, this description is here.

Comment: The "suggested staff" is merely a general suggestion.  In order to reach the third research milestone, you need *specific* staff, quite possibly including personnel not in that list.